# Spring Security Active Directory Ignoring PartialResultException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ldap

I have the following configuration in my spring security xml file. When I try to authenticate I get the following message but cannot proceed.

INFO: Ignoring PartialResultException

I am aware that spring's documentation states that you can set ignorePartialResultException  to true but this property seems to be in the LdapTemplate class which may require additional coding. I would like to accomplish all of this through bean configuration as I am not interested in role mapping.

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="activeDirectoryAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="activeDirectoryAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="mydomain.com" />
        <beans:constructor-arg value=" ldap://mydomain.com:389" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing from port 389 to 3268 to search the [Global Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/how-global-catalog-servers-work(v=ws.10).aspx) instead?  A search against the GC will never return referrals.  Also, have you tried changing your LDAP URL to something more specific so it doesn't search the whole domain?  For example, "ldap://mydomain.com:389/dc=foo,dc=bar"?

Comment: You "cannot proceed" or you "can proceed" after this INFO message?

Comment: I am not able to use 3268. I am not able to proceed after I receive the INFO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging around we found out that our role mapping was blocking the authentication. We were in fact hitting AD but Spring was trying to map a group name to a role that didn't exist within our system. Once we did that we were good to go.

Comment: Are you getting this error SpringSecurityLdapTemplate:235 - Ignoring PartialResultException.